# how can I retrieve the rows from .npy file based upon the specific key's value

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, key

I loaded the .npy file on colab using **f=np.load(path/to/file)**

[The structure of data looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dyTz.png)

When I try to see the keys of dictionaries in it, it displays

[The keys in the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzucU.png)

***Now I want to extract the rows based upon the values against key named "feature_path" as displayed in the image.***

Upon using the function to retrieve the values against key="feature_path"

**myDict = {}

for d in f:
c = d['feature_path']
myDict[c] = myDict.get(c,0)+1
print(myDict)
feature = myDict.values()
frequency = myDict.keys()
print(feature)
print(frequency)**

[if i just extract the values against this specific key it gives me an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWMhN.png)

Comment: does the first dict have this key?

Comment: That was an issue I couldn't notice. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my first dictionary didn't have that "Key" so I had to skip first row

I resolved it by editing

**for d in f[1:]:**